# How to get all the past values of a field in salesforce?

Tags: field-history, opportunity-history

I want to write a trigger on opportunity and whenever opportunity stage is updated to Closed Won, check if the stage was updated to  Closed Won in the past. If stage was updated to Closed Won in past, then throw error "Opportunity cannot be set to Closed Won twice!"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tracking all previous values, your requirement can easily be realised with a custom checkbox field on Opportunity that you set true when you first see the stage updated to Closed Won. You can use this flag in an appropriate validation rule, such that when the status changes to Closed Won (use ISCHANGED if possible) and the flag is TRUE then the rule is violated and the user is told they cannot set Closed Won more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpportunityFieldHistory to get the old value and use it in the trigger

```
Example:
[Select ID, Field, OldValue, NewValue from OpportunityFieldHistory where Field = 'Stage']
```

Comment: This would be far less efficient than holding a custom field as per my suggested answer. You also didn't show how the history would be related to a specific record nor how to do this in a bulkified manner.

Comment: @PhilW, yes I agree this could be done via a custom flag, but this could also handle in the trigger as well, for bulkified, need to use the collections, So I give the option to get the old value from history object and perform  SOQL.

Comment: You should show how the query works against the trigger context objects then. As it stands: you get all previous values (not just Closed Won) for all Opportunity records. And you don't mention enabling field history for the field of interest.